# why "NumPy operations convert Tensors to numpy arrays automatically"? how does this feature been implemented?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Reading TensorFlow docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/basics#numpy_compatibility

```py
import numpy as np

ndarray = np.ones([3, 3])

print("TensorFlow operations convert numpy arrays to Tensors automatically")
tensor = tf.multiply(ndarray, 42)
print(tensor)


print("And NumPy operations convert Tensors to numpy arrays automatically")
print(np.add(tensor, 1))

print("The .numpy() method explicitly converts a Tensor to a numpy array")
print(tensor.numpy())
```

> tensor = tf.multiply(ndarray, 42)

TF APIs support NumPy objects as inputs and this is easy to understand because TF APIs are just implemented to handle NumPy objects by TensorFlow Team.

But

> print(np.add(tensor, 1))

On the contrary, why NumPy APIs could handle a tf.Tensor is quite amazing to me.
Is this a mechanism that NumPy provided to handle any type of objects? 
Or just supported by Python in language level ? (I am new to Python)

Comment: It is a feature of numpy. If an object provides `__array__` function, it is called to retrieve a numpy array: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.dispatch.html?highlight=__array__

Comment: Be  careful.  It's a good idea to check what `np.asarray(tensor)` produces.

Comment: This tutorial says eager execution is on by default.  If it's not on, the `tensor` object might just be symbolic, and have a `not implemented` `__array__` methods.  There have been lots of SO questions about converting tensorflow objects to arrays.  I don't have tensorflow installed so can't speak from experience, but I sense that the conversion is often not as straightforward as this tutorial claims.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61028705/typeerror-cant-convert-cuda-tensor-to-numpy-use-tensor-cpu-to-copy-the-tens is an example where the `__array__` method is not enough.